# Где ставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Прочитал, что пунктуация дана для того, чтобы показать какие-то паузы, которые наметил автор текста. То есть теоретически я могу ставить знаки препинания где мне вздумается?

Если можно, напишите, пожалуйста, после каких слов или союзов всегда идёт запятая.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ зависит от характера человека. Например, злобный, завистливый человек всегда будет ставить запятую после слова "казнить" во фразе "казнить нельзя помиловать".

А *теоретически* - сначала надо поставить все запятые там, где этого требуют [Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации](http://ir2.ru/pravila-1956.htm#s32), а потом уже можно ставить "авторские" запятые ("где вам вздумается").

Comment: Нехороший это подход. 
Во-первых, "авторские" знаки возникают обычно именно там, где "Правила" допускают двоякую пунктуацию - в зависимости от смысла или интонации. Во-вторых, автор не должен ставить запятые "там, где вздумается". Автор должен очень хорошо понимать, зачем он это делает: по смыслу, интонации, облегчения восприятия или для передачи особенностей речи героя. Список, имхо, исчерпывающий, разве что в редчайших случаях - для снятия недоразумений понимания.
И при этом должен понимать, идет ли он на нарушение "Правил" или просто выбирает допускаемый, но неочевидный вариант.

Answer (score 2):

> Прочитал, что пунктуация дана для того, чтобы показать какие-то паузы, которые наметил автор текста.

В русской традиции это один из наименее значимых пунктуационных (и орфографических вообще) принципов. Обычно его относят к т.н. авторской пунктуации и трактуют следующим образом.  Автор имеет право поставить (или опустить) запятую в следующих двух случаях.
~1. Когда ни тот ни другой вариант не противоречить общим правилам грамматики, но при этом они имеют или могут разный смысл; а также для облечения понимания или прочтения (в.ч. вслух) написанного.
~2. Для передачи особенностей прямой речи героя, этот случай на саом деле является отступлением от правил, здесь его рассматривать не имеет смысла.

> То есть, теоретически, - я могу ставить знаки препинания где мне вздумается?

Теоретически - да, но только если Вы очень хорошо понимаете, зачем Вам это надо. Или это случай - из числа описанных выше.

Подробно - здесь.
http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_4_punct/
Вынужден оговориться, что у данного автора на многие вопросы весьма специфические взгляды, я не всегда их могу разделить, но полемизировать с ним здесь не буду.

> Если можно, напишите пожалуйста после каких слов или союзов всегда идёт запятая.

Вопрос, видимо, некорректно сформулирован. Запятая обычно определяется тем, что идет за ней, в не тем, что перед. И притом, *после* союзов запятые вообще крайне редки, если, конечно, сразу за союзом не идет какой-то обособленный оборот.
Могу вспомнить, что почти всегда обособляется, например, слово "пожалуйста", поэтому после него (как и перед) идет запятая. Как и перед нем.

Логичнее было бы ставить вопрос о том *перед* какими словами всегда ставится запятая. Но даже в этой постановке всегда все-таки надо заменить на "почти всегда".

Comment: Наша корректор (я работаю в газете) рассказывала, что на прошлой работе ей пришлось вычитывать сборник стихов. Так вот, там запятые стояли после каждого слова! Она поправила в соответствии с правилами пунктуации, на что автор стихов ужасно обиделся)))

Comment: На моей памяти еще было время, когда авторам говорили, что лишняя запятая - меньший грех по сравнению с её отсутствием. Или в другой формулировке: "Если хочется поставить, то ставь". Нечто подобное и у stopkran'а. В каком-то смысле такой подход был оправдан, ибо большинство сомнений и "авторских" знаков связаны с оборотам, которое проще обособить, чем обосновывать необособление. Но нельзя ж до абсурда доводить... А ныне мы как раз и имеем такой абсурд, когда обособляется все, что только в голову взбредет...  
ЗЫ Стихи - особая статья. Хозяин - барин.

Comment: Человек пишет:
"Запятая обычно определяется тем, что идет за ней, а не тем, что перед." И противоречит себе своим следующим предложением, в котором именно слово "притом" заставляет ставить после него запятую.
"И притом, после союзов запятые вообще крайне редки..."